Obtener eventos de calendarios compartidos Outlook
En mi aplicacion web tengo un calendario con integración con los eventos de Outlook de la cuenta que inicie sesión, uso la API de Microsoft Graph, en la cual tengo los permisos de API agregados de Calendars.Read, Calendars.Read.Shared y User.Read, los cuales también tengo activos en mi código.
Mi problema es que no consigo obtener los eventos de los calendarios a los que el usuario este suscrito además de los suyos propios.
Esta es la función con la que obtengo solo los eventos del calendario de la cuenta:
async function getCalendarEvents(accessToken) {
    // Obtener los eventos del calendario de Microsoft Graph API
    const response = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        // Manejar el caso de error al obtener los eventos del calendario
        const errorText = await response.text();
        console.error(`Error al obtener los eventos del calendario: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`, errorText);
        throw new Error('Error al obtener los eventos del calendario');
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    const events = [];

    function adjustToLocalTime(dateTime) {
        const date = new Date(dateTime);
        const timeZoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // Convertir minutos a milisegundos
        return new Date(date.getTime() - timeZoneOffset).toISOString();
    }

    // Función para extraer solo el texto de una cadena HTML
    function extractTextFromHTML(html) {
        const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
        return doc.body.textContent || ""; // Obtener el texto plano
    }

    // Procesar eventos recurrentes
    const recurringEvents = data.value.filter(event => event.recurrence && event.recurrence.pattern);

    recurringEvents.forEach(event => {
        const startDate = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
        const endDate = new Date(event.end.dateTime);
        const recurrence = event.recurrence.pattern;
        let instanceDate = new Date(startDate);
        const endRecurrenceDate = event.recurrence.range && event.recurrence.range.endDate ? new Date(event.recurrence.range.endDate) : null;
        // Obtener la descripción del evento recurrente
        const eventDescription = event.body ? extractTextFromHTML(event.body.content) : ''; // Agregar descripción
        // Obtener la localización del evento recurrente
        const eventLocation = event.location ? event.location.displayName : ''; // Agregar localización

        while (!endRecurrenceDate || instanceDate <= endRecurrenceDate) {
            if (!recurrence.daysOfWeek) {
                // Si no hay días de la semana específicos, agregar la instancia del evento
                const adjustedStartDate = new Date(instanceDate);
                adjustedStartDate.setHours(startDate.getHours());
                adjustedStartDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes());

                const adjustedEndDate = new Date(instanceDate);
                adjustedEndDate.setHours(endDate.getHours());
                adjustedEndDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes());

                // Verificar si la instancia está dentro del rango de la recurrencia
                if (adjustedStartDate <= endRecurrenceDate || !endRecurrenceDate) {
                    events.push({
                        title: event.subject,
                        start: adjustToLocalTime(adjustedStartDate.toISOString()),
                        end: adjustToLocalTime(adjustedEndDate.toISOString()),
                        allDay: event.isAllDay,
                        description: eventDescription, // Agregar descripción
                        location: eventLocation // Agregar localización
                    });
                }

                // Calcular la siguiente instancia según el patrón de recurrencia
                switch (recurrence.type) {
                    case "daily":
                        instanceDate.setDate(instanceDate.getDate() + recurrence.interval);
                        break;
                    case "absoluteMonthly":
                        instanceDate.setMonth(instanceDate.getMonth() + recurrence.interval);
                        break;
                    case "absoluteYearly":
                        instanceDate.setFullYear(instanceDate.getFullYear() + recurrence.interval);
                        break;
                }

                continue;
            }

            // Si el evento ocurre en días específicos de la semana
            const daysOfWeekIndices = (recurrence.daysOfWeek || []).map(day => {
                switch (day.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "monday":
                        return 1;
                            case "tuesday":
                        return 2;
                            case "wednesday":
                        return 3;
                            case "thursday":
                        return 4;
                            case "friday":
                        return 5;
                            case "saturday":
                        return 6;
                            case "sunday":
                        return 0;
                }
            });

            daysOfWeekIndices.forEach(dayIndex => {
                let tempDate = new Date(instanceDate);
                while (tempDate.getDay() !== dayIndex) {
                    tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + 1);
                }

                // Si tempDate está dentro del rango y es una instancia válida
                if (tempDate >= startDate && (!endRecurrenceDate || tempDate <= endRecurrenceDate)) {
                    const adjustedStartDate = new Date(tempDate);
                    adjustedStartDate.setHours(startDate.getHours());
                    adjustedStartDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes());

                    const adjustedEndDate = new Date(tempDate);
                    adjustedEndDate.setHours(endDate.getHours());
                    adjustedEndDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes());

                    // Verificar si la instancia está dentro del rango de la recurrencia
                    if (adjustedStartDate <= endRecurrenceDate || !endRecurrenceDate) {
                        events.push({
                            title: event.subject,
                            start: adjustToLocalTime(adjustedStartDate.toISOString()),
                            end: adjustToLocalTime(adjustedEndDate.toISOString()),
                            allDay: event.isAllDay,
                            description: eventDescription, // Agregar descripción
                            location: eventLocation // Agregar localización
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            // Mover instanceDate al inicio de la próxima semana según el intervalo de recurrencia
            instanceDate.setDate(instanceDate.getDate() + 7 * recurrence.interval);
        }

        // Verificar y agregar la última instancia si cae exactamente en el endRecurrenceDate
        if (endRecurrenceDate && recurrence.daysOfWeek) {
            const tempDate = new Date(endRecurrenceDate);
            const endRecurrenceDay = tempDate.toLocaleString('en-US', {
                weekday: 'long'
            }).toLowerCase();
            if (recurrence.daysOfWeek.includes(endRecurrenceDay)) {
                const adjustedStartDate = new Date(tempDate);
                adjustedStartDate.setHours(startDate.getHours());
                adjustedStartDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes());
                const adjustedEndDate = new Date(tempDate);
                adjustedEndDate.setHours(endDate.getHours());
                adjustedEndDate.setMinutes(endDate.getMinutes());

                // Verificar si la última instancia no es la misma que la fecha de finalización
                if (adjustedStartDate.getTime() !== endRecurrenceDate.getTime()) {
                    events.push({
                        title: event.subject,
                        start: adjustToLocalTime(adjustedStartDate.toISOString()),
                        end: adjustToLocalTime(adjustedEndDate.toISOString()),
                        allDay: event.isAllDay,
                        description: eventDescription, // Agregar descripción
                        location: eventLocation // Agregar localización
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //Procesar eventos individuales (no recurrentes)
    const singleEvents = data.value.filter(event => !event.recurrence);
    singleEvents.forEach(event => {
    const eventDescription = event.body ? extractTextFromHTML(event.body.content) : ''; // Agregar descripcion
    const eventLocation = event.location ? event.location.displayName : ''; // Agregar localización
        events.push({
            title: event.subject,
            start: adjustToLocalTime(event.start.dateTime),
            end: adjustToLocalTime(event.end.dateTime),
            allDay: event.isAllDay,
            description: eventDescription, // Agregar descripción
            location: eventLocation // Agregar localización
        });
    });

    // Imprimir los eventos procesados en la consola para depuración
    console.log("Eventos procesados FINAL:", events);

    // Devolver los eventos procesados
    return events;
}

EDIT: he cambiado la funcion y ahora si obtengo eventos de los calendarios compartidos y del mio pero se salta varios eventos y no carga todo el año.
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    const startDateTime = new Date(Date.UTC(currentYear, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString(); // 1 de enero del año actual
    const endDateTime = new Date(Date.UTC(currentYear, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59)).toISOString(); // 31 de diciembre del año actual

    // Helper function to fetch calendar events
    async function fetchCalendarEvents(calendarId, accessToken) {
        const response = await fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/${calendarId}/calendarView?startDateTime=${startDateTime}&endDateTime=${endDateTime}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorText = await response.text();
            console.error(`Error fetching events from calendar ${calendarId}: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`, errorText);
            throw new Error(`Error fetching events from calendar ${calendarId}`);
        }

        return await response.json();
    }

    // Fetch all calendars for the user
    const calendarsResponse = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
    });

    if (!calendarsResponse.ok) {
        const errorText = await calendarsResponse.text();
        console.error(`Error fetching calendars: ${calendarsResponse.status} ${calendarsResponse.statusText}`, errorText);
        throw new Error('Error fetching calendars');
    }

    const calendarsData = await calendarsResponse.json();
    const calendars = calendarsData.value;

    const allEvents = [];

    function adjustToLocalTime(dateTime) {
        const date = new Date(dateTime);
        const timeZoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // Convert minutes to milliseconds
        return new Date(date.getTime() - timeZoneOffset).toISOString();
    }

    // Function to extract text from an HTML string
    function extractTextFromHTML(html) {
        const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
        return doc.body.textContent || ""; // Get the plain text
    }

    for (const calendar of calendars) {
        console.log(`Fetching events for calendar: ${calendar.name} (${calendar.id})`);
        const data = await fetchCalendarEvents(calendar.id, accessToken);

        console.log(`Fetched ${data.value.length} events from calendar: ${calendar.name}`);

        data.value.forEach(event => {
            const eventDescription = event.body ? extractTextFromHTML(event.body.content) : ''; // Add description
            const eventLocation = event.location ? event.location.displayName : ''; // Add location

            allEvents.push({
                title: event.subject,
                start: adjustToLocalTime(event.start.dateTime),
                end: adjustToLocalTime(event.end.dateTime),
                allDay: event.isAllDay,
                description: eventDescription, // Add description
                location: eventLocation // Add location
            });
        });
    }

    // Print the processed events to the console for debugging
    console.log("Processed events FINAL:", allEvents);

    // Return the processed events
    return allEvents;
}

